# Window does not display on second monitor

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am trying to figure out why this code only works on my computer but not in another computer. Both location have dual screen. I want the queue window to be displayed in second monitor, but it just shows up on the first monitor and not maximized. Any ideas ?

```
Q = new queue();
util.showOnMonitor(1, Q);
Q.Show();
Q.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;

public static void showOnMonitor(int monitor, Window w2)
{
     Screen[] sc;
     sc = Screen.AllScreens;

     if ( monitor >= sc.Length )
     {
          monitor = 0;
     }


            w2.Left = sc[monitor].Bounds.Left;
            w2.Top = sc[monitor].Bounds.Top;

            w2.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;


}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the *other monitor* is 1 on the other computer?

Comment: Yes, in other location monitors can have other order. Windows desktop starts from left monitor, even it not main and task bar on other monitor. Try to add check for monitors positions.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I have thought of that before I posted here, so I tried change to 0 and 1.  The 0 will make the window appear on first monitor and maximized the window. But 1 will appear on first monitor also but not maximized and the right edge of window stick to the right edge of first monitor.

Comment: Okay, after make the second monitor as the main display then that 1 will cause it to go to the second monitor. But I don't want the second monitor as the main display, any other solution ? Btw both monitor have different resolution, the second monitor has lower resolution.

Comment: Found out that when the window is set to go to the second monitor, it does goes there, but in a split of milliseconds, it jump back to the first monitor. There must be a windows setting or external program that cause it so ?